# MacBook OS X Mavericks reinstallation

Tags: install

I'm trying to reinstall OS X Mavericks on a MacBook through internet the error that i receive is:
"This item is temporarily unavailable."

Answer (score 1):

For me at least, since I previously "purchased" Mavericks from the App Store, it showed up in my previous purchases list so I was able to download it. If you never actually installed Mavericks from the app store directly (i.e. upgraded an older Mac using the App Store) then it probably won't be there. This is a strange oversight on Apple's part - some apps out there still don't properly support Yosemite, and my workplace also has had problems with Yosemite working with their directory infrastructure, so we still use Mavericks as a matter of course.

If you didn't "buy" (read: download for free) Mavericks officially from the App store, your only option is to find a friend who did and ask them to create you a USB installation media. Instructions for doing this are easily found on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Since Apple has released the replacement for Mavericks called Yosemite, the Mavericks is no longer available on app store for download.

There are no official sources to get Mavericks.

You option is to find a friend or someone and get a copy from them.

Comment: Is it possible to create a bootable USB drive for installation? if so how?

Comment: Yes it is possible if you have the Mavericks Installer package. (5.3 Gig file)

Comment: Problem is I cannot find the package on the internet, any specific download links?

Comment: I had to download Yosemite, create a bootable usb using that. However, it worked great on my macbook (mid 2013). Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Great, it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, but the link to create a bootable installer once you have your hands on a downloaded installer is:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372